# J2ME No display when application is run

Tags: java, java-me, midp, lcdui

I am a .Net Developer and currently migrating to java. What am I missing here? There is no display when I run the program?

```
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class CalenderMIDlet extends MIDlet{
  private Form form = null;
  private DateField calender = null;  
  private static final int DATE = 0;

  public CalenderMIDlet(){
  calender = new DateField("Date In:", DateField.DATE, TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
  }

  public void startApp(){
  display = Display.getDisplay(this);
  Form form = new Form("Calender");
  form.append(calender);
  }

  public void pauseApp(){}

  public void destroyApp(boolean destroy){
  notifyDestroyed();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't set the `private Form form = null;`

Try this code

```
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class CalenderMIDlet extends MIDlet{
    private Form form;
    private Display display;
    private DateField calender;  
    private static final int DATE = 0;

    public CalenderMIDlet(){
        calender = new DateField("Date In:", DateField.DATE, TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    }

    public void startApp(){
        display = Display.getDisplay(this);
        Form form = new Form("Calender");
        form.append(calender);
        display.setCurrent(form);
    }

    public void pauseApp(){}

    public void destroyApp(boolean destroy){
        notifyDestroyed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> What am I missing here?

Well as far as I can tell your code misses to invoke [Display.setCurrent(Displayable)](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Display.html#setCurrent%28javax.microedition.lcdui.Displayable%29), that would request *"...that a different Displayable object be made visible on the display..."* (quoting API documentation).

> There is no display when I run the program?

This is expected behavior, taking into account above. Most likely if you invoke `display.setCurrent(form)` in startApp method, you'll see the form.

<sub>side note. I would also consider moving initialization of *calender DateField* from constructor into startApp. Per my recollection this way would be more reliable.</sub>

- also this part of startApp looks very fishy:
  `Form form = new Form("Calender"); /* why is 'Form' here? */`
  as far as I can tell removing `Form` would make much more sense

Comment: @Lion don't know what have you tried, but without `setCurrent` nothing will be displayed that's for sure

Comment: It's correct that without `setCurrent()` nothing is displayed. It just displays (with `setCurrent()`) `Date In: <date>`. I can't figure it out.

Comment: @Lion <date> is separate issue - this is typical (allowed) behavior when [DateField](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/DateField.html) date isn't set. It's harmless but if it is making you nervous, try something like `calender.setDate(newDate());` after you create that DateField

Answer (score 2):

Just use one following line of code in startApp() method

```
 public void startApp(){
  display = Display.getDisplay(this);
  Form form = new Form("Calender");
  form.append(calender);
display.setCurrent(form);
  }
```